# Unity DI for static member (for example in static class program) / when do members get populated

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library

I'm trying to get started with unity and I'm looking for help with this particular problem:
I already understand what dependency injection / unity is and how to do this programatically but I do not understand how/when members are populated when they are marked with the Dependency-Attribute.

```
class Program
{
    static Program()        
    {
        uContainer = new UnityContainer();
        var section =   (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(uContainer);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer uContainer;

    [InjectionMethod]
    public static void InjectTrace(ITraceManager traceManager)
    {
        trace = traceManager;
    }

    [Dependency]
    public static ITraceManager trace { get; set; }// = /*new WebTraceManager("C:\\","trace",true);//*/new EnterpriseLibaryLoggingWrapper(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Programmatically inject dependency
        // TODO: Do this via attributes
        //UnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
        //UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");

        //section.Containers["containerOne"].Configure(myContainer);
        //trace = myContainer.Resolve<ITraceManager>();
        trace.ProgramStatus("Start");
        trace.ProgramStatus("End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The uncommented section within Main that programatically sets the trace property works fine. But using the attribute "Dependency" the property will not be populated. 
Is there a missing call to the unity container?
Thank you for your help.

According to Steve's advice I've changed the example, using  an instance instead of static class:

```
 static Program()
    {
        uContainer = new UnityContainer();
        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(uContainer);
        Instance = uContainer.Resolve<Program>();
    }

    Program(ITraceManager traceManager)
    {
        trace = traceManager;
    }

    static readonly Program Instance;

    //Do not use Dependency Attribute
    //[Dependency]
    public  ITraceManager trace { get; set; }// = /*new WebTraceManager("C:\\","trace",true);//*/new EnterpriseLibaryLoggingWrapper(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        Instance.Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {            
        trace.ProgramStatus("Start");
        trace.ProgramStatus("End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But when calling

```
Instance = uContainer.Resolve<Program>();
```

, i recieve an exception telling me, that program is not registered within the container. Thats true, but should'nt
Unity return the by the program code known type Program with resolved dependencies instead?
The examples i found on the web always use constructor injection like this

```
IUnityContainer uContainer = new UnityContainer();
MyObject myInstance = uContainer.Resolve<MyObject>();
```

I finally found the problem with the injection constructor sample, of course the constructor has to be PUBLIC. The exception message made me a little bit confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few points:

- You currently seem to completely configure the container in XML. **Don't do that!** You should only configure the dependencies that can actually change after building (deployment configuration) in XML. For the rest, use code based configuration, because XML based configuration is very brittle, lacks compile time support, lacks intellisense support, and lacks expressiveness.
- **Don't use method injection** to initialize components. This leads to [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/). The main way of injecting dependencies is using constructor injection. Define all your dependencies on constructor parameters. All types that have dependencies should have a [single public constructor](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) that contain all the needed dependencies. Unity will automatically find that constructor and know how to invoke that constructor and inject the dependencies.
- **Don't use attributes at all!** This couples your code to the container used, while application code should be oblivious to the existence of the DI Container. Again, stick with constructor injection.

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for your advice. I modified my  example according to your hint (constructor injection) but since the program class is not registered, i get an exception when trying container.resolve instead of injected tracemanager. can you please have a ook on the example. thanks

Comment: "Unity will automatically find that constructor and know how to invoke that constructor and inject the dependencies."  Just like this ?: MyObject myInstance = uContainer.Resolve<MyObject>(); public MyObject(IDependency1 dep1){this.dependency1=dep1;}

Comment: Sorry for asking, it was a stupid mistake within my code, the constructor was not public, but it has to be public for Unity!

Comment: @user1430306: You typically wouldn't let Unity create your `Program` class. This class IS your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) and in the composition root you call `Container.Resolve` (probably just once) to get the root object(s) of your application containing the application logic. The Program class itself should not contain any other logic than that is needed to wire everything together and run the actual application.

Comment: Unity can configure property injection in lots of ways, you're not limited to attributes! For examples of using the APIs, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882(v=pandp.20).aspx